# Android: How to properly manage sequential threads within infinite loop

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, threadpool, intentservice

I have created `IntentService` with infinite loop inside the `onHandleIntent` then add static methods start,resume,pause,stop to directly call it within my Activities.

The scenario is, inside the infinite loop, I am calling callback methods which is creating a new thread to execute long process.

The problem is, I am worrying about continuously creating Threads due to infinite loop. I am pretty sure that there is better way to manage it. I am thinking of ThreadPool or something enable to use only one thread in a sequential manner. So that, I am saving time,memory,overheads etc..

OTHER APPROACH ARE VERY WELCOME. Ask me other information as needed. Then, I will update here.

Here are my codes(take a look at SampleCallback):

**IntentService**

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

public class SampleCallbackIntentService extends IntentService {
    private final String LOG_LOGCAT_TAG = "SampleCallbackIntentService";
    private Handler _handler;

    public SampleCallbackIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // initialize variables for pause & resume thread
        _mPauseLock = new Object();
        _mPaused = false;
        _mFinished = false;

        // initialize handler to switch to UI/Main thread
         _handler = new Handler()
            {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(final Message msg)
                {
                    _callback.doSomethingFromUIThread(msg);
                }
            };
    }

    private final SampleCallback _callback = new SampleCallback() {
        @Override
        public void doSomethingFromCurrentThread(final Object object) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //do long running process.
                                    // I will access object here.
                }
            }).start();

        }

        @Override
        public void doSomethingFromUIThread(final Message msg) {
            //may update UI here.
        }
    };

    private final int CALLBACK_MESSAGE = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(LOG_LOGCAT_TAG, "loop started");
        while (!_mFinished) {
            // do stuff here
            // create the object variable. Then pass to callback method
            _callback.doSomethingFromCurrentThread(object);

            // process and create the result to pass
            String someResult = "some result here";
            _handler.sendMessage(_handler.obtainMessage(CALLBACK_MESSAGE, someResult));

            synchronized (_mPauseLock) {
                while (_mPaused) {
                    try {
                        Log.i(LOG_LOGCAT_TAG, "loop paused");
                        _mPauseLock.wait();
                        Log.i(LOG_LOGCAT_TAG, "loop resumed");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_LOGCAT_TAG, "error occured on pause", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                //using sleep here might be not good design.
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_LOGCAT_TAG, "error occured on sleep", e);
            }
        }
        Log.i(LOG_LOGCAT_TAG, "loop ended");
    }

    private static Object _mPauseLock;
    private static boolean _mPaused;
    private static boolean _mFinished;

     public static void start(Context context) {
         Intent service = new Intent(context, SampleCallbackIntentService .class);
         if(context.startService(service)==null) {
             Log.e(LOG_LOGCAT_TAG, "Service cannot be started");
         } else {
             Log.i(LOG_LOGCAT_TAG, "start() called");
         }

     }

    /**
     * Call this on pause.
     */
    public static void pause() {
        Log.i(LOG_LOGCAT_TAG, "pause() called");
        synchronized (_mPauseLock) {
            _mPaused = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Call this on resume.
     */
    public static void resume() {
        Log.i(LOG_LOGCAT_TAG, "resume() called");
        synchronized (_mPauseLock) {
            _mPaused = false;
            _mPauseLock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

     public static void stop() {
         if(_mPauseLock == null) return;
         synchronized (_mPauseLock) {
             Log.i(LOG_LOGCAT_TAG, "stop() called");
             _mFinished = true;
         }
     }
}
```

**SampleCallback**

```
import android.os.Message;

public interface SampleCallback {

    public void doSomethingFromCurrentThread(final Object object);

    public void doSomethingFromUIThread(final Message msg);
}
```

**UPDATES1**
I am using location api aside from google api. I will create a android library project and use that api to get the latest location (e.g. every 2secs) in the background.

On the application side, just need to call static methods to use it (e.g. start(context, callback), pause(), resume(), stop()). It has callbacks to obtain the location. After obtaining the needed information from the location object, I will create a new thread to call my own created callbacks (which implemented by the application side).

Comment: does this even work? in `stop()` u are making use of non-static member `_mPauseLock`. Is this even possible?

Comment: @Sherif oh thanks for pointing it out. consider it as compiled source code. i will change it to static.

Comment: I have added information concerning of what I want to achieve.

Comment: Why can't you use `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates` for this?

Comment: @Idolon I am using other location api (not google api), it has no LocationManager.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of creating a new thread every time? AsyncTask manages a fixed pool of threads (or one background thread - depending on Android version) and allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

However I wonder why do you need to create an infinite loop inside the `onHandleIntent` method? By doing that you prevent your [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) from receiving further Intents. Since in IntentService:

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as
>   long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop),
>   but only one request will be processed at a time.

I think you want to execute some long-running code out of the UI thread in the IntentService. But that doesn't require the creation of an infinite loop in the IntentService worker thread. Just send the requests as needed to the IntentService using [`Context.startService(Intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) call. If you want IntentService to send back some result or just call a callback in the UI thread you can pass a [`Messenger`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html) (or a [`ResultReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html)) object with the Intent.

**Activity**:

```java
final Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

private void postTask() {
  Intent intent = new Intent("com.yourservice.DOACTION");
  intent.putExtra("messenger", new Messenger(handler));
  intent.putExtra("object", YourObject());   // pass other Parcelable objects
  startService(intent);
}
```

**IntentService**:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
  Messenger messenger = intent.getParcelableExtra("messenger");
  YourObject object = intent.getParcelableExtra("object");

  //... do work here ...

  Message msg = Message.obtain();
  msg.what = CALLBACK_MESSAGE;
  msg.setData(someResult);
  messenger.send(Message.obtain()); 
}
```

Comment: or just one process then create an infinite loop to call startService?

Comment: I doubt you need infinite loop at all. What will you do in it? Obtain information from sensors or just wait for another message? But it is not suitable for neither of those tasks. If you want to do some task in background and notify subscribers use plain Service instead of IntentService - just start `AsyncTask` from `Service.onStartCommand` and call `messenger.send` upon AsyncTask completion.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the docs for [ExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) (not to be confused with Android Services) and the [Executors](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) package. There are a few examples there on how to use thread pools.

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure of proposing ThreadPool. It could be help of using ExecutorService/Executors in my case above? If yes, how could be?

Answer (score 0):

So wait, why do you need to use all these callbacks? Can't you just have each intent encode what needs to be done and then have your onHandleIntent execute different code based on the information of the intent. This is the way IntentService is intended to be used.

You shouldn't be doing any of the thread handling in the IntentSerivce. The IntentService is supposed to be handling all the threading code (and you should let it because it's probably highly optimized).

Comment: I'm still not convinced you need to do all these gymnastics just to accommodate your callbacks. I feel like you could implement this more simply using Handlers and just a straight up IntentService.